# How install php55 and php7 on Centos

Tags: centos, software-installation, php

I have php55 actually and httpd.
I would like to install also php7 (with php 55) or only php 5.6 - I mean php version 5.6, not php56.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. What operating system are you using? What exactly do you want to install (you mention 5 different php versions). Why is httpd relevant? Do you need to both install it and have your webserver use it? You need to explain what you are trying to do in order for us to be able t help you.

Comment: What is the difference between "php version 5.6" and "php56" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compile and package additional versions of PHP yourself using different compile time option to make them work from different path.

To do that, please read your distro specific documentation.

You could also try to use a PHP slotting system if you don't need them to run concurrently.
For example, Gentoo uses the "[eselect](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PHP#Running_multiple_versions_of_PHP)" tool for that purpose, your distro may have a similar tool.